# text overlap over image button in android when replace text by setText()

Tags: textview, android

When am trying to change the text in TextView with a large text it overlap over the ImageButton

Please see the image, the text overlap over the back button image

[image]

Here below we add the layout

```
 <RelativeLayout    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 

       <LinearLayout    
            android:id="@+id/segment_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_btn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/action_back" 
            android:background="@layout/actionbar_button_state"/>

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/seperatorViewAfterBack"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/action_btn_back"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>




        <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/detailsTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="19dip"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layout_group"
                    />



        <LinearLayout    
            android:id="@+id/layout_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"> 


        <View 
            android:id="@+id/seperatorView"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_btn_new_related"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/action_new" 
            android:background="@layout/actionbar_button_state"/>

        </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

initially the image button is hidden, we make it visible from our code using

```
ImageButton imgbtnBack = (ImageButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.action_btn_back);
        imgbtnBack.setVisibility(0);


TextView detTitle = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.detailsTitle);
    detTitle.setText("Order of This is for the account name maximum length supported");
```

please help me to avoid this overlapping problem

Answer (score 0):

Add  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/segment_back"  in the TextView